# Directed graph - node level CSS styles

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, visualization, data-visualization

I found this excellent example and sample code for drawing directed graphs - http://bl.ocks.org/cjrd/6863459
However, the graph-creator.css file defines a global style for all nodes. What if I want to assign different styles to certain "special" nodes from all other nodes (I want them to be different shapes and also differently colored and if possible also a different transparency). How would I modify this code to add these node specific effects?

Comment: You can simply add css 'id' or 'class' and apply css targetting them

Comment: So right now, there is a global CSS defined in the html file. If I were to have a different CSS for a specific node, where and how in the JS file would I point that node to not the global but this different (non global) CSS file?

Comment: I will put a complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose to `append` different shapes here based on different scenario:

```
// append new elements in <g> element in scenario X
// you can pass different parameters for specific styling here
// for example, user select "red" color rect in setting filters

newGs.append("circle")
  .attr("r", String(consts.nodeRadius));

// alternatively append rect
newGs.append("rect")
  .attr({
    "x": // mouse event info as circles in the demo
    "y": // mouse event info as circles in the demo
    "width": String(consts.rectWidth),
    "height": String(consts.rectHeight)
  })
  .attr("class", "myRectStyle") // set styles in css 
  .attr("fill", "red")
  .attr("rx",5)
  .attr("ry",5)
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve the goal, first you must understand the `CSS` concepts. First of all you can place a `CSS` for a `HTML/SVG` markup in 3 places.

External `CSS` file, 
Same `HTML` File with a `<style>` block
Inline `CSS` inside the tag eg. `<circle> <li> <line>` etc.

In your case, if you want to give different styles for different nodes, then you can give them specific css `class/id` selectors and have styles in any of the 3 methods I have mentioned previously.

Let's say you want to make certain circles transparent, then just give the circles a class "`trCircles`" and specify the CSS in a external CSS file and link the file with `<link>`

```
 d3.select('g')
     .append('circle')
     .attr('class', 'trCircle')
...
```

in the CSS file you can have.

```
.trCircle{
 fill : transparent;
}
```

Orr if you want to apply them in the d3 level. You can specify it when you create the circle.

```
d3.select('g')
 .append('circle')
 .attr('cx' , '100')
.....
 .style('fill','transparent')
;
```

Hope you get the idea.